# C# Replace part of a string

Tags: c#, string, replace

How can I replace part of a string that has a potentially unknown starting index. For instance, if I had the following strings:

```
"<sometexthere width='200'>"
"<sometexthere tile='test' width='345'>"
```

I would be looking to replace the width attibute value that can have an unknown value and as mentioned before an unknown start index.

The I understand that I would somehow have to base this on the following part, which is constant, I just don't quite understand how to achieve this.

```
width='
```

Comment: This looks like a job for ... [Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html)!

Comment: +1 for finding creative way to bypass standard answers for "how to parse HTML with RegEx" and "I want to parse and construct XML with string manipulations".

Comment: @jrummell: This looks like a job for a parser. This does not look like a job for regular expressions.  First off, regular expressions do not take into account the grammar of the markup, and second *every regular expression posted here so far is wrong*.

Comment: No, this looks like a job for ... [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: @EricLippert I concede to your wisdom. [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) was very enlightening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
Regex reg = new Regex(@"width='\d*'");
string newString = reg.Replace(oldString,"width='325'");
```

This will return a new string with a new width, provided you put a number between the ' ' in the new width field.

Answer (score 35):

So far you've got seven answers telling you to do the wrong thing. **Do not use regular expressions to do the job of a parser.** I am assuming that your string is a hunk of markup. Let's suppose it is HTML.  What does your regular expression do with:

```
<html>
<script>
    var width='100';
</script>
<blah width =
              '200'>
... and so on ...
```

I'd be willing to bet as much as a dollar that it replaces the JScript code, which it should not, and does not replace the attribute of the blah tag -- it is perfectly legal to have whitespace in an attribute.

If you have to parse a markup language then **parse the markup language**. Get yourself a parser and use it; that's what parsers are for.

Comment: I'm glad someone mentioned this. I thought the exact same thing, when I read the other answers.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) class, you can search for the content of the attribute and repalce the value with this class.

Off the cuff [Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx) might do the trick:

```
var newString = Regex.Replace(@".*width='\d'",string.Foramt("width='{0}'",newValue));
```

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 2):

Use the regular expression

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\b(width)\b\s*=\s*'d+'");
```

where the `\b`s indicate that you wish to match a whole word, `\s*` allows for zero or any number of whitespace charaters and `\d+` allows for one or more numeric placeholder. To replace the numeric value you can then use:

```
int nRepValue = 400;
string strYourXML = "<sometexthere width='200'>";

// Does the string contain the width?
string strNewString = String.Empty;
Match match = regex.Match(strYourXML);
if (match.Success)
    strNewString = 
        regex.Replace(strYourXML, String.Format("match='{0}'", nRepValue.ToString()));
else 
    // Do something else...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why *one* whitespace character? **XML allows for unbounded whitespace**.

Comment: Amended - I am not sure why I did that :]. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression (RegEx) to find and replace all the text in single quotes after "width=".

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression, like `(?<=width=')(\d+)`

Example:

```
var replaced = Regex.Replace("<sometexthere width='200'>", "(?<=width=')(\\d+)", "123");"
```

`replaced` is now: `<sometexthere width='123'>`

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions to achieve this:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

string yourString = "<sometexthere width='200'>";

// updates width value to 300
yourString = Regex.Replace(yourString , "width='[^']+'", width='300');

// replaces width value with height value of 450
yourString = Regex.Replace(yourString , "width='[^']+'", height='450');
```

Comment: Assuming the width attribute is always a numeric value. Not necessarily a valid assumption.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx).
Something like this to replace the width value with `123456`.

```
string aString = "<sometexthere tile='test' width='345'>";
Regex regex = new Regex("(?<part1>.*width=')(?<part2>\\d+)(?<part3>'.*)");
var replacedString = regex.Replace(aString, "${part1}123456${part3}");
```