# Replace part of string

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, .net-3.5, c#-3.0

I'm having difficulty with the following.

In VB.Net, I have the following line:

`Dim intWidgetID As Integer = CType(Replace(strWidget, "portlet_", ""), Integer)`

where `strWidget = portlet_n`

where `n` can be any whole number, i.e.

`portlet_5`

I am trying to convert this code to C#, but I keep getting errors, I currently have this:

`intTabID = Convert.ToInt32(Strings.Replace(strTabID, "tab_group_", ""));`

which I got using an online converter

But it doesn't like `Strings`

So my question is, how to I replace part of a string, so `intTabID` becomes `5` based on this example?

I've done a search for this, and found this link:
[C# Replace part of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9609042/c-sharp-replace-part-of-a-string)

Can this not be done without regular expressions in c#, so basically, I'm trying to produce code as similar as possible to the original vb.net example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like this `strTabID.Replace("tab_group_", string.Empty);`

```
    int intTabID = 0;
    string value = strTabID.Replace("tab_group_", string.Empty);
    int.TryParse(value, out intTabID);

    if (intTabID > 0)
    { 

    }
```

And in your code i think you need to replace "tab_group_" with "portlet_"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Strings.Replace(strTabID, "tab_group_", "")`, use `strTabID.Replace("tab_group_", "")`.

Comment: I'm now getting the following error message `Compiler Error Message: CS1501: No overload for method 'Replace' takes '3' arguments`.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was too quick with my answer: you're using `strings` instead of `string`, but also the method is different: it's an instance method.  See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Their is no Strings class in Vb.Net  so please use the string class instead http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903372(v=vs.71).aspx

you can achieve it by this way

```
string strWidget = "portlet_n";

int intWidgetID  = Convert.ToInt32(strWidget.Split('_')[1]);
```

Comment: I'm now getting the following error message `Compiler Error Message: CS1501: No overload for method 'Replace' takes '3' arguments`.

Comment: @oshirowanen please see another way of achieving it

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
int intWidgetID = int.Parse(strTabID.Replace("tab_group_",""));//Can also use TryParse
```